# How to use DOM .appendChild() in EJS

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, dom, ejs

I am trying to make a "div" element on my EJS web page compiling messages from clients received by the server. But there is an error ".appendChild(div) is not defined". How should I fix that?

```html
<div class="box box-widget col-md-12">
        <div class="box-footer box-comments" id="message">
            <div class="box-comment">
                <div class="comment-text">
                    <span class="username">
                        Maria Gonzales
                        <span class="text-muted pull-right">8:03 PM Today</span>
                    </span>
                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                    by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-comment">
                <div class="comment-text">
                    <span class="username">
                        Maria Gonzales
                        <span class="text-muted pull-right">8:03 PM Today</span>
                    </span>
                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                    by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
const socket = io();

socket.on('User Connected', currentUserData => {
    console.log(currentUserData);
    outputData(currentUserData)
});

function outputData(currentUserData){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('box-comment');
    div.innerHTML = `<div class="comment-text">
        <span class="username">
            Maria Gonzales
            <span class="text-muted pull-right">8:03 PM Today</span>
        </span>
        ${currentUserData}
    </div>`;
    document.querySelector('.box-footer box-comments').appendChild(div);
};
```

Comment: use `document.querySelector('.box-footer.box-comments').appendChild(div);` or even better `document.getElementById('message').appendChild(div);`

Comment: Your question is **very** unclear. You've provided **completely separate** code snippets for the HTML and JavaScript so they can't interact with each other. You've mentioned EJS, but there is no sign of any EJS code in the question. The JS you've provided looks like client-side code and not EJS or Node.JS code (although you tagged this Node.JS too). You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like you just made a typo and forgot the `.` from the `box-comments` selector.